# Is his nobs/knobs separate from a flush in cribbage?

Tags: cribbage

I've been hunting everywhere for this and am leaning toward the answer being yes but can't find it explicitly stated anywhere: is his nobs (or knobs) separate from a flush in cribbage? For example, would a hand of of all hearts (1,2,3,J) and a starter card of a 4 of hearts... would you award 5 points for the flush *and* a point for knobs? Or just 5 points for the flush since the matching suit of the jack and starter card are already counted in the flush?

I'm new to the game and thus perhaps my lack of playing with more experienced players and having this situation actually come up has not occurred. I still can't find it online. Rule sites will list a flush and knobs but not state what to do when both occur.

Thanks!

Comment: The flush/starter card special rule you may be thinking of is that a flush in the crib must include the starter.  So four hearts in the crib with a club starter is not a flush.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nobs is counted separately. It will always be one extra point if it is in your hand or in the crib. Likewise, nibs (if a jack is cut for the dealer) is always two points, and the dealer still gets to count the jack for a flush if the suit matches.

[Rules of Cribbage](http://www.cribbage.org/rules/rule1.asp#section7).

Comment: Awesome -- that was my hunch, but thanks for confirming! I'd upvote you but don't even have the points to do so :)

Comment: For the record:  The proposed hand of A23J of hearts, with 4 of hearts as starter, would score a total of 14 - A4J is 15 for 2, 23J is 15 for 2 more, the A234 run is 4, A234J flush is 5, and the knob is 1.